# Can we determine whether $f\in L^{p}$ or not ; if we know $\hat{f}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, lp-spaces

Let $a_{n}:=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}$ and $a_{0}= c$  where $c$ is some constant.

Clearly, $a_{n}\in \ell^{2}(\mathbb Z)$, that is, $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |a_{n}|^{2}< \infty.$

We define the function 
$$f(t):= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} a_{n} e^{int}, (e^{it}\in \mathbb T, \  t\in \mathbb R)$$

By the [Riesz-Fischer theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Fischer_theorem),  it follows that $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb T).$ We also note that $L^{p}(\mathbb T) \subset L^{2}(\mathbb T), (p>2).$

> **My Question**: (1) Is it true that $f\in L^{p}(\mathbb T), (p>2)$?

(2) If we know $\hat{f} \in \ell^{2}(\mathbb Z);$  in which situation one can expect $f\in L^{p}(\mathbb T)(p>2)$? (Of course, in general one can not expect this, for instance there exist $f\in L^{2}$ which is not in $L^{p}$)

Answer (score 4):

Since $\hat{f}\in\ell^1\implies f\in L^\infty$ and $\hat{f}\in\ell^2\implies f\in L^2$, [Riesz-Thorin interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem) guarantees that

> If $\hat{f}\in\ell^q$ where $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$ and $1\le q\le2$, then $f\in L^p$

Therefore, since the $\hat{f}$ you give above is in $\ell^q$ for all $q\gt1$, we have that $f\in L^p(\mathbb{T})$ for all $p\lt\infty$. However, it may not be in $L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$. In fact it won't since the series for $f(0)$ diverges.

Comment: @r; here $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)|= \infty;$

Comment: So how does the above arguments are useful? Or am I missing something? Thanks;

Comment: @Inquisitive you do have $\hat f \in \ell^q$ for all $q > 1$, just not for $q=1$.

Comment: I don't completely understand how divergence at **one** single point disproves $f \in L^\infty$. After all, we are only interested in boundedness away from a null-set.

Comment: @PhoemueX: if $f\in L^\infty$, it would be bounded. However, as $x$ approaches $0$, $f(x)$ approaches $\infty$. In fact, $f(x)=-\log(2-2\cos(x))$.